# XXXX is not compatible with monoandroid10.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I have a Xamarin project that builds just fine on my local machine but is not building on the azure server. Anyone see this before ?

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1201: Project XXX.XXXX.XXXXX is not compatible with monoandroid10.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0). Project XXX.XXXX.XXXXX supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you update nuget on Azure to the latest version?

Comment: I am using  NuGet 4.4.1 let me see

Comment: I had two different errors in Azure that were nuget related. At the time I set nuget to version 5.8 which solved the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your nuget version to 5.8 and this will all go away :)

Comment: Doesn't work!  nuget version 5.11.2 and problem persists.

Comment: Did you try and downgrade to 5.8 ?

Comment: No. I passed the problem with version 5.11.2. Maybe reason in my case is terrible internet connection and invalid path to project (It has spaces and special characters).

Comment: Oh well my issue was using azure devops internet connection issue would not be a problem there unless your doing it on your local machine

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure pipelines to Build and deploy Xamarin apps, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). And if you use [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), its build environment is different from local machine, such as it may lack of some software or installs different software version. You can see the installed software for each hosted agent by choosing the **Included Software** link in the table.

To your issue, please check which NuGet version do you use to build this project locally, and then use the [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) in Azure pipeline to specify this NuGet version(*maybe 5.8.0 works for your issue as Mouse commented*) to build your project with [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Also you could [deploy local self-hosted Windows agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and use it in Azure pipeline to build your project, which will run local build environment.

BTW, you could refer to this doc: [Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) to make initial troubleshooting steps when encounter pipeline issues.

Comment: Thanks Edward I have used version 5.8.0 and I got pipeline invalid I am building Android so I am using a windows build agent.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You could deploy a self-hosted Windows agents following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops to run your local build machine to check the result.